# Changing text color in RichEditBox

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm using the new `RichEditBox` in Windows 8 and attempting to select a text range and change the text color. The code below will underline and change the background of the selected text however the `ForegroundColor` does not change, the text just remains black.

```
result.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "Hello World");            
var range = result.Document.GetRange(0, 5);

range.CharacterFormat.Underline = Windows.UI.Text.UnderlineType.DoubleWave;
range.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
range.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
```

How do you change the text color for an `ITextRange` inside the `RichEditBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates` to see the changes to text.

```
result.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
```